# Delaunay() function MATLAB Purpose

Tags: matlab, delaunay

I want to generate triangle meshes in MATLAB with the delaunay function in 2-D. So I declare
the X- and Y- values and set tri=delaunay(X,Y). Then I use triplot to plot it. However, 
what does tri give me? Does it give each of my triangle a special designation number? 
 After reading through some of the MATLAB tutorials I still DON'T
understand it.

Comment: Also, is there anyway to designate each triangle as 1,2,3....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delaunay` function returns `tri` as an `Mx3` matrix of triangle connectivity, where each of the `M` triangles is represented as an integer triplet that indexes into the `X,Y` vertex position arrays.

It's probably easier with a simple example:

```
%% a simple square box
X = [0.0; 1.0; 1.0; 0.0];
Y = [0.0; 0.0; 1.0; 1.0];

%% an example output from delaunay()
tri = [1,2,3  %% 1st triangle connects vertices 1,2,3
       1,3,4  %% 2nd triangle connects vertices 1,3,4
      ];
```

The triangles are just numbered linearly - `tri(1,:)` is the first triangle, `tri(n,:)` is the nth triangle etc. If you wanted to re-order the list of traingles you could permute the array, but the indexing would always have to be linear - if there are `M` triangles the indexing must encompass `1:M`.

Hope this helps.